# Adding a new initial state to WorkItem type Bug - Web Acess task board shows error TF400917

Tags: tfs, customization, workitem

I am using TFS 2012 (Update 4).

After adding a new initial state **New** to my Bug work item workflow
the backlog and the task board show the error:

> **TF400917**: The current configuration is not valid for this feature.
>   This feature cannot be used until you correct the configuration.

I tried to fix this by adding a new line in the common process configuration :

> ```
> < BugWorkItems category="Microsoft.BugCategory"><States>
>   <State type="New" value="Proposed" />
>   <State type="InProgress" value="Active" />
>   <State type="Complete" value="Closed" />
>   <State type="Resolved" value="Resolved" />
> </States>
> ```

But importing this via witadmin - I get the error:

> witadmin.exe importcommonprocessconfig /collection:< my collection> /p:Kanban  /f:d:\tmp\CommonProcessConfig_Kanban_new.xml
>
> **Line: 5 Position: 14 - The 'type' attribute is invalid - The value 'New' is invalid according to its datatype 'StateFieldEnum' - The Enumeration const
>   raint failed.**

Which types (and meta types) are valid for my Bug work item and where is this StateFieldEnum defined?

In the field explorer the field **System.State** has a allowed value **New**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the error myself. It was the correct approach to edit the BugCategory.

I have swapped the type and value - the correct xml to import is:

```
<BugWorkItems category="Microsoft.BugCategory">
    <States>
      <State type="Proposed" value="New" />
```